# How do we pass errcontext to ErrorException?

Tags: php, exception, error-handling

Whenever an error is handled by error_exception ([`set_error_handler`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.set-error-handler.php)), the arguments passed in include:

1. **errno**, the first parameter, contains the level of the error raised, as an integer.
2. **errstr**, the second parameter, contains the error message, as a string.
3. **errfile**, the third parameter (optional), contains the filename that the error was raised in, as a string.
4. **errline**, the fourth parameter (optional), contains the line number the error was raised at, as an integer.
5. **errcontext**, the fifth parameter (optional), is an array that points to the active symbol table at the point the error occurred. In other words, **errcontext** will contain an array of every variable that existed in the scope the error was triggered in. User error handler must not modify error context.

However, the constructor of [`ErrorException`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.errorexception.php) does not include a way to pass in **errcontext**.

Why doesn't ErrorException include errcontext parameter? Is there something inherently *dangerous* in doing so?

```
set_error_handler(function($errno, $errstring, $errfile, $errline, $errcontext){
    if(error_reporting() === 0){ // means expression uses @ sign
        return true; // prevent default
    }
    throw new ErrorException($errstr, $errno, 0, $errfile, $errline);
    // how do we pass in errcontext ?
});
```

If we need to pass in the errcontext parameter, do we need to create our own exception subclass to do so?